# sublime 3 inactive selection tag

Tags: sublimetext3, textmate, color-scheme

I am in middle of modifying Monaki theme, I want to change color of inactive select. when I double click something sublime automatically highlight other occurrence of the word in the document.

[image]

I am aware of `caret` but caret is just the border, what i want to achieve is to change the background of caret.

I searched a lot but couldn't find any documentation to list these tags and valid input for them.

I also tried `inactiveSelection` but had no luck with it.

so I have two questions. 
first, how can I achieve this and change the color of the auto select?
second, is there any documentation out there that I can read about all the valid key/strings.

for example, in code bellow

```
<key>bracketContentsForeground</key>
<string>#16F24D</string>
<key>bracketContentsOptions</key>
<string>foreground underline</string>
```

how can I know `<key>bracketBackground</key>` is a valid code or what about `<key>bracket</key>` ? or `<string>foreground underline</string>` is there any other value that i can put inside the `<string>`? I see many ppl modifying the themes, but i can't find the source that they are learning from. I don't mind if I need to read inside the code to see what is the available tag, but I don't know to read which file.

Comment: Don't know the answer. Want to make sure you know about this great online theme editor: http://tmtheme-editor.herokuapp.com/#/theme/Monokai

Answer (score 0):

**selection** key and **inactiveSelection** key

e.g., for monokai.tmTheme

selection string try #343400

inactiveSelection try #341700